# Twilio - AvailablePhoneNumbers search by keyword

Tags: php, web-services, rest, voice, twilio

In my project I need to develop an autocomplete in order to allow users to search and reserve Twilio Toll-Free phone numbers.

Well, it's not a problem to communicate with Twilio REST API for me, but it makes me crazy since it works in quite strange manner.
So, initially I have got some string, part of phone number, and I need to get all those numbers which contain that string.

As described [here](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers#toll-free), I use *Contains* parameter to provide the keyword to Twilio.
Twilio returns me different numbers, but none of them really contain the keyword.

You can say that I did not read the documentation carefully, and for got to append '*' character to my keyword. I tried to append them, but result is the same.
I can not logically explain why I get not those numbers which I request.
The only possible theory - Twilio compares the keyword not against the phone number itself, and against some other it's property.

Twilio developers, evangelists, please share your suggestions - What am I doing wrong? It a very simple task. Is it impossible to implement normal phone numbers search with Twilio API?

```
$search = array('InPostalCode' => '', 'NearNumber' => '', 'contains' => '888******');
$numbers = $twilio->account->available_phone_numbers->getList('US', 'TollFree', $search);
```

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.

Can you post the code you're using the make the request?  Are you making a direct request against the REST API, or are you using the PHP helper library?

Comment: Added short piece of code

Comment: Try changing 'contains' to 'Contains' (upper case C).

Comment: @DevinRader Try adding you comment as an answer - I want to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Change the 'contains' parameter to 'Contains' (upper case 'C').  [The API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers#local) is case sensitive.

Hope that helps.